# Video is paused after switching to mini view then clicking on Task view

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I have UWP Media Player app and when i switch to mini view and click on Task View video is paused.
Has anyone encountered such a problem? I need help

1. Launch the application.
2. Add any video file.
3. Enter full screen.
4. Click on Task view.
5. Observe.
6. Switch to mini view.
7. Again click on Task view.
8. Observe.

[image: Video on task view]

Comment: What does "Switch to mini view" in the step 6 mean? Do you mean exit Full Screen first and then again click on Task view? If it is, I exit Full Screen and click on Task view, the video is still playing, it isn't paused. If it isn't, can you show more details about the behavior of "Switch to mini view"?

Comment: No, i mean picture in picture mode (overlay)

Comment: We have noticed this problem and given feedback through internal channels.